# Trying to get crossbrowser videos to play, but apparent conflict with jQuery(?)

Tags: jquery, video, cross-browser

I have a page with several videos, among which a viewer may choose one to view at a time. I've gotten it to work in Chrome 18.0 and Safari 5.1, but that's it.

html:

```
<div class="video" data-id="1" >
<video width="auto" height="100%" controls="controls">
  <source src="videos/cadillac_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="videos/cadillac_x264.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="videos/cadillac_x264.webm" type="video/webm" />
<object data="videos/cadillac_x264.mp4" width="auto" height="100%">
  <embed src="videos/cadillac_x264.swf" width="auto" height="100%" />
</object> 
</video>
</div>
```

There are six of the above divs.

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('div.video').hide();

$('.icon').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id'),
        thisDiv=$("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']"),
        thisVideo=$("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']").find('video');

    $('video').each(function () {
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime=0;
    });

       $('div.video').not(thisDiv).fadeOut();

       thisDiv.fadeIn();      
       thisVideo.get(0).play();   
});
});
```

The console in FF 11.0 says:

```
WalkingDomProcessor.process: Can't find engine for: http://mysite.com/directory/index.php
```

and:

```
An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
[Break On This Error]   

this.currentTime = 0;
```

And in IE 8:

```
this.pause();

Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I thought I'd covered all my bases in viewing videos in all browsers, and was under the impression jQuery worked pretty well with all modern browsers.

To be sure, I've got all the videos in the correct directories, and am apparently calling the scripts correctly.

Why am I getting these errors? Why aren't the videos playing?

Sorry for the length of this post, but I just wanted to be thorough.